# Only search DataTables on valid query

Tags: datatables

If I have a searchable `$().dataTable` object, how can I prevent the search from firing on invalid data?

For example, suppose I want the search to only be executed when all of the search's characters are numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default event handler(s) and use `isNaN()` to evaluate the input :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  initComplete: function() {
    var api = this.api();
    $('.dataTables_filter input').unbind().bind('keyup', function() {
      if (!isNaN(this.value)) {
        api.search(this.value).draw()
      }
    })
  } 
})
```